# Trains - can aerofoils reduce friction?

Tags: friction, drag, aerodynamics, lift, efficient-energy-use

Trains need energy to overcome friction at the wheel-rail interface during constant high speed speed running.

Aerofoils on the roof could provide lift, reducing the friction and potentially saving fuel. Would the energy saving be enough to overcome the increased drag caused by the "wings"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: I am not an engineer, but I think this would be detrimental.

The train doesn't actually have to overcome friction at the contact points. In fact, friction is what allows the wheels to roll. If there's not enough friction, the wheel will start to slip and THIS would cause massive energy waste. In fact, the amount of friction dictates how much torque and acceleration you can apply without slipping. That's why car wheels are made of a material that has a good "grip" on the road (maximizing friction).

In fact, the losses experienced at the wheel/rail interface are called *rolling resistance*, and stem mostly from non-elastic deformations. The mechanism is different, but the outcome is similar; engineers define a rolling resistance $F$ proportional to the normal force (weight of the trains, $P$), similar to sliding friction:
$$F=CP$$
From Wikipedia, a reasonable and pessimistic order of magnitude for $C$ would be $C\approx10^{-3}$.

Now, let's look at the action of your airfoils. They generate a lift force $L$ and drag $D$. The lift will reduce the effective weight in the rolling resistance equation to $P-L$, while the drag is just the bad guy of your story. To make our conclusion safe, let's take an incredibly optimistic  lift/drag ratio $L/D=20$ (super "efficient" airfoils).

The new rolling resistance can be calculated as follows:
$$F_{new}=C(P-L) = CP-20CD \approx F_{normal}-0.02D$$
Therefore, with this quick and dirty (and optimistic) estimation, we see that the reduction in rolling resistance is only about 2% of the drag force introduced. So your airfoils will end up being detrimental. This is not mentioning the fact that you will indeed reduce the wheel friction, which is detrimental as we established (reducing the maximum torque you can apply before slipping).

I need to stress that I am no engineer, and can't guarantee that my answer is following a good "train" of thought. This is only some common sense and quick estimations, that seem to point out that the drag introduced will massively overshadow the rolling resistance reduction.

Comment: If there's not enough friction to maintain rolling,  there's certainly not much "sliding" friction either, so I disagree with that point.

Comment: Agreed. I'm not sure what point you're referring to.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft is referring to the 'energy loss' because of slippage.

Comment: Oh got it, but a slipping situation basically amounts to rotating the wheels for nothing (since it is not making the train go forward as it slips), with at least some energy loss. Therefore, I consider that having your wheel slipping is pure energy waste, basically grinding the wheel on the rail for no result. Furthermore, thinking about it, stopping the rotation of a wheel train at full speed is not exactly child's play. So the friction can actually be sizeable while still allowing the wheel to slip. But I don't wanna get too off-tracks, this is a bit remote from the core of the question

Answer (score 5):

The friction that trains must overcome is almost purely air resistance, not rolling resistance. Rolling a steel wheel on an equally hard surface (i.e. the rails) is extremely efficient.

Adding wings to the train would only increase aerodynamic drag, in particular if the wings generate lift (the thing to look up here is called ['induced drag'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift-induced_drag)).

Btw, also for cars and bicycles the drag greatly outways the rolling resistance at all but the slowest speeds.

Comment: Exactly.  Compare with those boats which use "airfoils" under the water to raise the hull out of the water, thus drastically reducing the water-induced drag.